# Rotating screensavers using webpages

Tags: windows, c#

Is there some free software that can handle rotating screensavers using webpages? I have a few pages from my servers which I would like to display on my desktop screen whilst they are updating.

I have looked around for software but most of them are outdated. The closest option I have found so far is https://www.finalhit.com/products/live-screensaver-creator/, however this is only trial mode.

If there is nothing out there, perhaps there's an alternative? maybe a c# program using windows form?

Comment: Why *using webpages*? That sounds like an unnessary extra step. Something that loads pictures from disk is far simpler.